# Laplace transform problem initial value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Consider the initial value problem $y''+49y=\cos(7t), \quad y(0)=9, \quad y'(0)=3$. Solve for $y(t)$.

Until now, I have found that $$Y(s)=\frac{s}{(s^2+49)(s^2+49)}+9\frac{s}{s^2+49}+3\frac{1}{s^2+49}$$

I have trouble with the first factor $$\frac{s}{(s^2+49)(s^2+49)}$$ because I can not find a useful way to solve it. By partial fractions I have found nothing useful.

Comment: Hint: recall that $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(f\cdot g) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}(f)*\mathcal{L}^{-1}(g)$, where $*$ denotes convolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reverse engineering... $\mathcal L \{tf(t)\} = -\frac {d}{ds} \mathcal L\{f(t)\}$

$\frac {s}{(s^2 + 49)^2} =  -\frac{d}{ds}\frac 12\frac {1}{s^2 + 49}$